# macOS check if application is running by path

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsworkspace

I have a path string to application. For example `/Users/username/Applications/MyApp.app`
All that I need, is to check is it running or not.

I've tried to compare bundle path of running applications with path that I have:

```
-(BOOL)isApplicationAtPathRunning:(NSString *)applicationPath {
    for (NSRunningApplication * application in NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace.runningApplications) {
        if ([application.bundleURL.absoluteString isEqualToString:applicationPath]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

But if application was moved to another folder `application.bundleURL` of running application will be the old one.
Please suggest, thanks!

Comment: If you just care about the app "identity", you should use `NSBundle` to get the bundle ID of the app bundle at the path and compare that to the bundle ID (`bundleIdentifier`) of the `NSRunningApplication`. If you really care about whether the bundle's executable is the precise file that the process is running even if it's been moved, that will be harder. You may need to run `lsof` in a subprocess and parse its output.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I think lsof is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 4):

Better check the application by bundle identifier

```
-(BOOL)isApplicationWithBundleIdentifierRunning:(NSString *)bundleIdentifier {
    NSArray *applications = [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier: bundleIdentifier];
    return applications.count > 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advise! But if the application was started from another bundle's executable this function will return YES.